# High latency using Firebase hosting as compared to native Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I am getting higher latency when invoking Cloud Run using Firebase as described in the below tutorial.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run

Response time:

Firebase hosting invoking Cloud Run: **785ms**(relatively very high as compared to native Cloud Run response time)

Native Cloud Run: **170ms**

Note: We are using the same region/location for Firebase and Cloud Run: asia-northeast1

What you expected to happen:
Latencies from both should be comparable or the same.

1- Call any URL from Firebase hosting invoking Cloud Run(refer attached screenshot)
[image]
2- Call any URL from Native Cloud Run(refer attached screenshot)
[image]

Comment: Did you repeat many time the test? Are you sure that  your Cloud Run container was warm when you performed your Firebase to Cloud Run test?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, Cloud Run was warmed up(not a first request to container). I am getting 'always' unusual latency compared to native Cloud Run compared to Firebase endpoint.

Comment: Do you know the latency implied by Cloud Run and this only for Firebase? In other word, what is the firebase latency with a call to Cloud Run?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am not sure. Actually, as per Google docs, I can serve dynamic content from Cloud run inside firebase hosting. This means firebase is acting proxy server and transfer data from cloud run to hosting. But my concern is why I am getting unusual latency when invoking Cloud Run from Firebase hosting. More details can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run

Comment: I'm aware about latency issue on Cloud Run when custom domain is used. In your case, you perform an URL rewriting to Cloud Run, and it's maybe the same issue known on Google side.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I was also thinking the same from Cloud Run known issues page: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#latency-domains. But I am very surprised to know Google moved Cloud Run to GA with this known issue(very critical in terms of production application) with Firebase hosting(Google's own product). Do you suggest any resolution to avoid this situation? I have already raised it via issue tracker(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145009271) but no response or acknowledgement from Cloud Run team.

Comment: I don't have solution for this issue, but I pushed your case to the google thread about the latency (I'm in the Alpha program of Cloud Run).

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks. I will be waiting for this fix.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340031/firebase-hosting-adding-450ms-latency-overhead-to-cloud-run