# Firebase Hosting adding ~450ms latency overhead to Cloud Run

Tags: firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have a Firebase Hosting site that maps the `/api` path to a Cloud Run app, as described in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run

Comparing the latency I get when accessing my API endpoint via Firebase Hosting compared with accessing the Cloud Run app directly, Firebase Hosting is adding an average of 450ms of latency. The app is hosted in us-west1, and I am located in the Seattle area.

```
% hyperfine --warmup 3 'curl -H "Authorization: $AUTH" https://staging.radiopaper.com/api/exchange'
Benchmark #1: curl -H "Authorization: $AUTH" https://staging.radiopaper.com/api/exchange
  Time (mean ± σ):     660.9 ms ±  85.2 ms    [User: 25.0 ms, System: 10.5 ms]
  Range (min … max):   575.5 ms … 856.9 ms    10 runs
```

vs

```
% hyperfine --warmup 3 'curl -H "Authorization: $AUTH" https://api-server-klkjcchm4q-uc.a.run.app/api/exchange'
Benchmark #1: curl -H "Authorization: $AUTH" https://api-server-klkjcchm4q-uc.a.run.app/api/exchange
  Time (mean ± σ):     212.5 ms ±  72.7 ms    [User: 27.8 ms, System: 9.9 ms]
  Range (min … max):   124.3 ms … 325.6 ms    11 runs
```

Is this the expected behavior? If so, it doesn't make much sense for me to run my Cloud Run app on the same domain as my static content.

Comment: This is definitely not an expected behaviour, but it can happen for a number of reasons. I don’t think it’s possible to help much on this question on stackoverflow, thus I recommend you to raise a direct request with GCP support. If you don’t have a support contract you can contact free [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: You may want to test with default Firebase domain of "*.firebaseapp.com", to filter out any issues with the DNS provider.

Comment: @GouravB, I repeated the experiment with the firebase hosting domain, same ~400ms difference.

Comment: @ZeenathSN, sounds good - I'll put together a minimal set of steps to repro with the standard "echo-server" test container and file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not an expected behaviour, but it can happen for a number of reasons. One of the reasons can be that the Firebase Hosting’s origin has to reach back out to the Cloud Run once it gets the request so there are multiple hops involved with routing through Firebase Hosting. We're working on making this better but don't have anything specific to share on that yet.

GCP Support Here! If you want to triage this, we will need specific details to find the root cause, thus I recommend you to raise a direct request with GCP support. If you don’t have a support contract you can contact free [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).